# How to find out which item the recycler view is snapped to?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view that uses `LinearSnapHelper` to snap the items as the user scrolls it. Now, I'd like to listen to the snaps, preferably getting the index of the item that was snapped. However, I can't really figure out if there's a way to do that.

Initially I thought that the `LinearSnapHelper`'s `findTargetSnapPosition()` would return the index to snap (as the documentation says), however this isn't true. It randomly returns -1 or 0 for the first item, and when the list is scrolled, it gets randomly invoked. Sometimes, the method's not called at all; sometimes, the index is incorrect, and sometimes it's correct. It seems that it's no use trying to find the index using this.

So: How would I find out which item the recycler view snaps to?

Answer (score 9):

I managed to get this working. I'm not sure if it's the best solution, but here's what I did:

```
private int selectedPosition = -1;
private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    LinearSnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper() {
        @Override
        public View findSnapView(RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager) {
            View view = super.findSnapView(layoutManager);

            if (view != null) {
                final int newPosition = layoutManager.getPosition(view);

                if (newPosition != selectedPosition && recyclerView.getScrollState() == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    onViewSnapped(newPosition);
                    selectedPosition = newPosition;
                }

            }

            return view;
        }
    };

    ...
}

private void onViewSnapped(int index) {
    // YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer.!